# Difference between unrestricted VECM and restricted VECM?

Tags: r, time-series, cointegration, autoregressive, stationarity

What's the difference between an **unrestricted** and a **restricted** VECM?

I believe a hint lies within the `cajorls()`[[1](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/urca/docs/cajorls)] function of R language's `urca`[[2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urca/urca.pdf)] package.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are you interested in the difference between interpretation or estimation of the restricted versus unrestricted model? Or still something else? You would probably agree that the basic idea of a difference between an unrestricted model and a restricted model is that in the restricted model some (often linear) combination of coefficients is assumed (in theory) and forced (in estimation) to be equal to some number. This should apply to VECM, too. E.g. one or a few of the VECM coefficients could be forced equal zero. So what do  you not understand?